# Change tomcats default URL

Tags: tomcat, tomcat8

I have 2 runnings tomcats (version 8).
1 is reachable via http://localhost:8080/ .
All other apps of this tomcat are reachable as expected on:

- http://localhost:8080/manager (Tomcats manager app)
- http://localhost:8080/myApp
- http://localhost:8080/docs (Tomcatdocumentation)
- http://localhost:8080/examples (Tomcats jsp examples)

The second tomcat is reachable via http://localhost:9090/ . (Other port)
But I need an other difference. I would like to change the URL prePath like the following:

- http://localhost:9090/test/manager (Tomcats manager app)
- http://localhost:9090/test/myApp
- http://localhost:9090/test/docs(Tomcatdocumentation)
- http://localhost:9090/test/examples (Tomcats jsp examples)

I tried a lot with `Context` element in `server.xml` and `context.xml`. But nothing meets my requirement.

I would like to have a path prefix, also for the ROOT as http://localhost:9090/test/ .

I don't know how to, so does someone knows a good solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution would be to deploy all relevant applications under a `test` folder.

e.g. move `tomcat-${version}/webapps/examples` to `tomcat-${version}/webapps/test/examples`.

You can also copy the contents of the `ROOT` folder into the newly created `test` folder to achieve the same ROOT functionality for `http://localhost:9090/test`.

Comment: #boo_radley Thank you. I tried your solution. It works for all but not for the tomcats manager directory in webapps.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with tomcats manager directory/folder that I renamed it to "test#manager" and my Application will be now deployed as "test#myApp.war" to directory/folder: "test#myApp".

Now I can reach the manager with http://localhost:9090/test/manager and my App with http://localhost:9090/test/myApp.

So to get a default URL for manager, examples and apps you can go with renaming the folders as described. To get a default url of the root you have to go as #Boo Radley described in the other answer.

There is no new folder necessary.
Start, Stop, Deploy and Undeploy webapps should work.

**Background:**
You can give directories a context with a prefix like "yourContext#" to the given directory or .war described at https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/context.html in table of examples in (Introduction -> 2. Naming) section.